# Bootstrap - collapsed sidebar by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I have a project based on bootstrap 3.3.7. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a toggle button connected to sidebar. So when a user clicks the button, a sidebar shows from the left. This is the code which I currently have:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
  <nav id="sidebar">
  
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      
    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <p>Dummy Heading</p>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Home</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
          <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
      <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to the article</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- Page Content Holder -->
  <div id="content">
          <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                                
                            </button>
      <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 3</h2></div></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sidebarCollapse").on("click", function() {
    $("#sidebar").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar a,
#sidebar a:hover,
#sidebar a:focus {
  color: inherit;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active > a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before,
a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\e259';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\e260';
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#content p a {
  color:
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

The code works but I do have an issue - I want to have the sidebar hidden all the time. So only a click on the button shows it. I have went through a bootstrap docs yet there is no class/info how to enhance this code with such functionality.

thanks for any hints..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have switch the parameter of `active` class, if so you can also eliminate the last mediaquery . Try this

```
.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar a,
#sidebar a:hover,
#sidebar a:focus {
  color: inherit;
}

#sidebar {
  margin-left:-250px;
}
#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active > a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before,
a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\e259';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  content: '\e260';
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#content p a {
  color:
}
```